# How can I save panel and restore it in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel in windows Form, including picture boxes, labels, etc. I supposed that it is possible to save the values of the control as a string in JSON format and then restore them by deserializing. but, as I have images in the PictureBox, it takes a lot of memory to save them as a string in the JSON file. Is there any alternative approach for saving the panel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serializing a PictureBox with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533724/serializing-a-picturebox-with-json) and [How to serialize only inherited properties of a class using a JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063259/how-to-serialize-only-inherited-properties-of-a-class-using-a-jsonconverter) and [Save WinForm or Controls to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669522/save-winform-or-controls-to-file)

Comment: Yes. It helped a lot. Thanks!